# проблема со слайдером

Tags: html, jquery, css

Добрый день. На сайте есть слайдер, который хочу заменить на этот:

```js
jQuery(function() {

  jQuery('#allinone_bannerRotator_attractive').allinone_bannerRotator({
    skin: 'attractive',
    width: 1920,
    height: 600,
    width100Proc:true,
    responsive:true,
    thumbsWrapperMarginBottom:-10,
    defaultEffect: 'random'
  });  
   
   
});
```

```html
<head>
    
  <link href="http://www.responsivejqueryslider.com/allinone_bannerRotator.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://www.responsivejqueryslider.com/js/jquery.touchSwipe.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="http://www.responsivejqueryslider.com/js/allinone_bannerRotator.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <!--[if IE]><script src="js/excanvas.compiled.js" type="text/javascript"></script><![endif]-->
<!-- must have -->
    
        
</head>

<div id="allinone_bannerRotator_attractive" style="display:none;">
            <!-- IMAGES -->
  <ul class="allinone_bannerRotator_list">
      <li data-bottom-thumb="images/attractiveFullWidth/thumbs/01_attractive.jpg" data-text-id="#allinone_bannerRotator_photoText1"><img src="http://www.responsivejqueryslider.com/images/attractiveFullWidth/01_attractive.jpg" alt="" /></li>
      <li data-bottom-thumb="images/attractiveFullWidth/thumbs/02_attractive.jpg" data-text-id="#allinone_bannerRotator_photoText2" data-link="http://codecanyon.net/user/LambertGroup?ref=LambertGroup" data-target="_blank"><img src="http://www.responsivejqueryslider.com/images/attractiveFullWidth/02_attractive.jpg" alt="" /></li>
      <li data-bottom-thumb="images/attractiveFullWidth/thumbs/03_attractive.jpg" data-text-id="#allinone_bannerRotator_photoText3"><img src="http://www.responsivejqueryslider.com/images/attractiveFullWidth/03_attractive.jpg" alt="" /></li>
      <li data-bottom-thumb="images/attractiveFullWidth/thumbs/04_attractive.jpg" data-text-id="#allinone_bannerRotator_photoText4"><img src="http://www.responsivejqueryslider.com/images/attractiveFullWidth/04_attractive.jpg" alt="" /></li>
      <li data-bottom-thumb="images/attractiveFullWidth/thumbs/05_attractive.jpg" data-text-id="#allinone_bannerRotator_photoText5"><img src="http://www.responsivejqueryslider.com/images/attractiveFullWidth/05_attractive.jpg" alt="" /></li>
  </ul>
                
                
                
   <!-- TEXTS -->
  <div id="allinone_bannerRotator_photoText1" class="allinone_bannerRotator_texts">
        <div class="allinone_bannerRotator_text_line textElement11_attractive_FullWidth" data-initial-left="50" data-initial-top="10" data-final-left="50" data-final-top="40" data-duration="0.5" data-fade-start="0" data-delay="0">Up to 5 types of banners</div>
        <div class="allinone_bannerRotator_text_line textElement12_attractive_FullWidth" data-initial-left="50" data-initial-top="10" data-final-left="50" data-final-top="92" data-duration="0.5" data-fade-start="0" data-delay="0.3">Each with <a href="http://codecanyon.net/user/LambertGroup?ref=LambertGroup" target="_blank">multiple</a> SKINS</div>
   </div>       

   <div id="allinone_bannerRotator_photoText2" class="allinone_bannerRotator_texts">
        <div class="allinone_bannerRotator_text_line textElement21_attractive_FullWidth" data-initial-left="1160" data-initial-top="60" data-final-left="1160" data-final-top="60" data-duration="0.5" data-fade-start="0" data-delay="0">16 transition effects<br /> for images</div>
        <div class="allinone_bannerRotator_text_line textElement22_attractive_FullWidth" data-initial-left="1160" data-initial-top="175" data-final-left="1160" data-final-top="175" data-duration="0.5" data-fade-start="0" data-delay="0.3">optional can set the transition<br /> for each image</div>
   </div>  

    <div id="allinone_bannerRotator_photoText3" class="allinone_bannerRotator_texts">
        <div class="allinone_bannerRotator_text_line textElement31_attractive_FullWidth" data-initial-left="480" data-initial-top="60" data-final-left="70" data-final-top="60" data-duration="0.5" data-fade-start="0" data-delay="0">Animated text from any direction</div>
        <div class="allinone_bannerRotator_text_line textElement32_attractive_FullWidth" data-initial-left="0" data-initial-top="100" data-final-left="70" data-final-top="100" data-duration="0.5" data-fade-start="0" data-delay="0.3">top, bottom, left and right</div>
        <div class="allinone_bannerRotator_text_line textElement33_attractive_FullWidth" data-initial-left="70" data-initial-top="250" data-final-left="70" data-final-top="165" data-duration="1" data-fade-start="0" data-delay="0.5">Any color, CSS and HTML formated</div>               
   </div>  

   <div id="allinone_bannerRotator_photoText4" class="allinone_bannerRotator_texts">
        <div class="allinone_bannerRotator_text_line textElement41_attractive_FullWidth" data-initial-left="90" data-initial-top="0" data-final-left="90" data-final-top="400" data-duration="0.5" data-fade-start="0" data-delay="0">Line One is here</div>
        <div class="allinone_bannerRotator_text_line textElement42_attractive_FullWidth" data-initial-left="90" data-initial-top="384" data-final-left="90" data-final-top="360" data-duration="0.5" data-fade-start="0" data-delay="0.3">Line Two over there</div>
   </div>

  <div id="allinone_bannerRotator_photoText5" class="allinone_bannerRotator_texts">
        <div class="allinone_bannerRotator_text_line textElement51_attractive_FullWidth" data-initial-left="90" data-initial-top="52" data-final-left="90" data-final-top="52" data-duration="0.5" data-fade-start="0" data-delay="0"><a href="http://codecanyon.net/user/LambertGroup?ref=LambertGroup" target="_blank">Cool Title Right Here</a></div>
        <div class="allinone_bannerRotator_text_line textElement52_attractive_FullWidth" data-initial-left="430" data-initial-top="115" data-final-left="90" data-final-top="115" data-duration="0.5" data-fade-start="0" data-delay="0.5">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <a href="http://codecanyon.net/user/LambertGroup?ref=LambertGroup" target="_blank">consectetur</a> adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt. </div>


   </div> <!--       -->                                                  

</div>
```

Этот код сохраняю в *banner.php* и когда отдельно открываю все работает. Но если вставляю на прямую или каким либо другим способом на *index2.php*, то ничего не отображается.

Вот код *index2.php*
 [ссылка на мой сайт index2.php](http://geosky.ge/index2.php)

Если можно помогите.

Answer (score 0):

Сложно ответить на такой вопрос, не имея исходных данных.

Можно посоветовать обдумать проблему логически: почему то, что работает само по себе, не отображается, если поставить его куда надо?

Часто это бывает из-за того, что неверно прописаны пути к JS, картинкам и т.п.

Попробуйте отладить код, если он работает в одном месте, то должен работать и в другом при соблюдении корректных условий. А если не работает, то что-то некорректно указано.

Comment: я просто уже все перепробовал все что мог. я мог бы вам как то показать здесь код index2.php ?

Comment: В комментариях неудобно, лучше на онлайн ресурсах типа jsfiddle или других, хотя бы даже Pastebin.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/VE0Bw46N

Comment: если сможете, пожалуйста помогите

Comment: Куда надо вставлять код баннера (например, номер строки)? Хорошо бы еще код banner.php.

Comment: Спасибо вам, только что разобрался)) просто на сайте были разные версии jquery и поэтому ничего не показывалось

Comment: Значит, мой ответ верен :)